# How can I switch off exception handling in MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, exception

Does anybody know how to switch off exception handling option in MSVC? I tried to set the option 'Enable C++ exceptions' to 'NO' and I got warning:
warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify `/EHsc`.

I would like to switch off the exception handler, too, but I don't know how.

In my application I basically need more speed than stability, therefore I chose switching off the exception handling. I do not have any `try`/`catch` blocks, but I do use STL. When I switch the option 'Enable C++ exceptions' to 'NO' is there any way how to get rid of those warnings?

Comment: Disabling exception handling won't buy you much, if anything, in terms of performance. Setting up an exception frame in x86 is cheap. With x64 exceptions are truly zero-overhead; no code is added for the non-throwing code path at all. You *might* benefit from better optimization options available to the compiler or smaller binary sizes, but either way expect the improvements to be miniscule.

Answer (score 28):

Most likely you're including one or more standard C++ headers that contain try/catch. The most typical case would be `<iostream>` - you will get this error on a file which consists of a single line that just includes that. Any other stream header will also do, as will locales.

If you look closely at the error message, it should reference two filenames, not one - your file, and the included file with the error. E.g. in my sample case of `#include <iostream>`, I get this:

```
except.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
```

Comment: As a side note, I must add that there really isn't such a thing as ANSI/ISO C++ without exceptions - the language spec doesn't even consider "disabling" them, and the entire standard library - including STL - uses exceptions. Even the containers use them, e.g. std::vector::at()

Comment: So this means if I never use any STD libraries in my code, I won't waste any CPU time/code size on useless exceptions?

Answer (score 22):

If you really don't want exceptions in the STL that will be linked to your program, define `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0` in your whole project. Better than compiling your code with `/EHsc` if you don't plan on adding exception handling.

Comment: define _HAS_EXCEPTIONS 0 makes my exe 4KB bigger
Enabling exceptions makes it another 4KB bigger.
Disabling setting and _HAS_EXCEPTIONS 0 removes warning and keeps the exe smaller.

Answer (score 4):

That warning means that you told the compiler you're not going to use exceptions yet you have a `try {} catch() {}`  block in the code. It informs you that although you have that block, if an exception is thrown no desctructors are going to be executed. Turning exceptions off means exactly that - the compiler doesn't produce code for automatic destruction when the stack is unwound in the event of an exceptions.

Comment: Well, I searched the code, but I don't have any try/catch blocks there. Yet, I create some classes using 'new', does it apply to that too?

Comment: No. This is a compiler warning, it appears when compiling a single cpp file. The name of the file appears just before the warning. That's the file which contain the offending code. Worst case you can try to selectivly comment out parts of the file to see what causes the warning.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, `/EH` is found at Configuration Properties ➔ C/C++ ➔ Code Generation ➔ Enable C++ Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Switching off exceptions is quite hard, as you're dealing with C++ here. It's really in the same category as switching off NULL pointers - how are you going to handle memory allocation failure, for instance?

That said, /EH specifies *which* exception handling model you want, and "none" is not an option. You can pick /EHa, /EHs, /EHac and /EHsc - [a]ynchronous with or without support for throwing extern "C" functions.

Comment: hmm, i don't agree with that. didn't c++ promise to not have any feature in it that you don't want (exceptions, RTTI)?

Comment: @didito: The theory is that you don't pay for them, if you don't use them. That's why there's no standard option to turn them off: the standard expects them to be free if unused, so there would never be a benefit to turning them off. (A typical way to achieve this is a table-driven mechanism, demand-loaded when an exception is thrown.)

Comment: This is a troll answer.  I dont use exceptions and you can turn them off.  You are not forced to use the STL either.  Its not part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have try/catch block(s) in your code?

The first thing to do when you get stuck is look up the error on MSDN and/or Google for it. That usually helps. This is what MSDN says:

> When the /EHsc option has not been enabled, an object with automatic storage in the frame, between the function doing the throw and the function catching the throw, will not be destroyed. However, an object with automatic storage created in a try or catch block will be destroyed. [...]

Comment: Yeah, that's what i found first and i have no clue what i'm doing wrong, because i don't have the vocabulary yet to understand this three sentences correctly. Can someone explain this warning without RTFM please? Thx.

Comment: edit: This site explains the /EHx-parameter of MS-C++-Compiler CL and gives a better clue what it does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Using MSVC aka CL one can simply use the /kernel switch or not have any /EH switch. Windows C/C++ MSVC builds always have [SEH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft-specific_exception_handling_mechanisms#SEH). SEH is inbuilt in Windows.

If `#if _HAS_EXCEPTIONS == 0` , MS STL will simply switch to SEH.

Is that standard C++? No it is not. Three keywords will be missing: try, throw and catch. And you need to learn about SEH.

So is that a "good thing"? Well for Windows low level C++, SEH is a good thing.

ps: It is not advisable to use `/kernel` switch, outside of kernel developments.