# Is there a way to know if exceptions have been disabled?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to know if exceptions have been disabled in C++?

I'm developing an application that uses exceptions and I want to avoid having the user compile the application with exceptions disabled, like a warning that you need exceptions.

Comment: Any disabling of exceptions is dependant on the used tools, libraries, OS... => the answer to your question depends on that too. And standard C has no exceptions.

Comment: @deviantfan: Standard *C++*, however, has loads of exceptions.

Comment: If you are compiling SOURCE code (including headers) with "no exceptions" and there is some code that throws exceptions, it will be an error in the compiler (at least in g++ and clang++) - in other words, the code won't compile.

Comment: @deviantfan: Welp, maybe you shouldn't have responded to something that was no longer part of the question. It's confusing.

Comment: I added C as tag, my bad, but let's follow the subject...
@MatsPetersson - in MSVC it does, but replace exception for abort.

Comment: May depend on the version, but this seems to imply at least warnings:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552695/how-can-i-switch-off-exception-handling-in-msvc

Comment: Here it pop ups a warning message informing that the application has called the abort function. - Using MSVC 2013 (the latest one)

Comment: Sounds like the time you add a special build-step that compiles a "test.cpp" and which contains a `try { throw something; } catch(...) { exit 0; }`, and then compile that using the default settings, run it and check that it exited nicely.

Comment: Or simply thoroughly document the behaviour... ;)

Comment: Yes, but anyway, I will accept your answer, I will leave the original behavior of MSVC about disabling exceptions... it will abort the application anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard certainly does not entertain such a functionality.

Assuming you are using a modern and competent compiler to compile code that contains a `throw`, then the compiler will error. But you can of course compile one part of the code WITH exceptions, and another without, in which case you still get exceptions thrown, but no way of catching them (since there is no `catch` either). So the program will probably terminate on first exception being thrown.

If you supply headers, you could just add a dummy function in an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace {
   inline void dummy_dummy_my_thing_to_check_exceptions()
   { 
       throw 123;
   }
}
```

and never even call that function, it will still fail to compile.

I doubt that any compiler that lets you turn off exceptions will accept code that does this - I have tried with g++ 4.8.2, g++ 4.6.3, clang++ 3.6.0 (as of three weeks ago) and clang++ 2.9. All give an error for the above function inside a headerfile. If I remove `-fno-exceptions`, the code compiles and runs (with a terminate becuase the code does `throw 1` in a function.

Total code:

x.h:

```
extern int func();

namespace {
    inline void dummy_dummy_my_thing_to_check_exceptions()
    { 
    throw 123;
    }
}
```

x.cpp:

```
int func()
{
    throw 1;
}
```

except.cpp:

```
#include "x.h"

int main()
{
    func();
}
```

Compiles with:

`g++ -c except.cpp && g++ except.o x.cpp`

or

`clang++ -c except.cpp && clang++ except.o`,

but won't compile with:

`g++ -c except.cpp -fno-exceptions && g++ except.o x.cpp`

or

`clang++ -c except.cpp -fno-exceptions && clang++ except.o`.

Comment: Your're right... I use GCC, MinGW, MinGW W64, CLang, and MSVC... All of them compile my without errors, and if I try to disable exceptions in GCC and CLang it doesn't compile, but does in MSVC, which I don't want to. That is the reason of the question, detect disabling of exceptions and avoid compiling.