# Adding -fno-exceptions flag in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, json, exception, visual-studio-2019

I need to add this flag to the compiler in visual studio but I don't know how to do this.

I have already tried some solutions but none worked.

Someone that has the same issue or knows the solution?

Comment: Does this question helps you? [How can I switch off exception handling in MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552695/9222996)

Comment: Otherwise you could go to Properties --> C/C++ --> All Options --> Additional Options and add your option there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Noone of the 2 solutions worked unfortunately but i found an easier way:

just define `JSON_NOEXCEPTION`

```
#define JSON_NOEXCEPTION
```

Comment: This may work for one particular library, but `-fno-exceptions`  turns it off everywhere.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.